# Mvel how to set value

Tags: java, mvel

I need to set value of an attribute if MVel expression is true.
Can any one please help me, how to do that.

Example code as below:

```
      LineItem lineItem = new LineItem();

      Address address = new Address();
        address.setAddress1("ABC");
        address.setAddress2("PA");

      lineItem.setShipFromAddress(address);

    ParserContext parserContext = ParserContext.create();
    parserContext.stronglyTyped().withInput("lineItem",LineItem.class)
          .withInput("shipFromAddress", Address.class);

        Object compiledWithSet = MVEL.compileExpression("( shipFromAddress.address1 contains 'ABC' || shipFromAddress.address1 contains 'ABC DEF' ) && (shipFromAddress.address2 contains 'PA') ? setShipFromLocation('PA1') : ",parserContext);
        MVEL.executeExpression(compiledWithSet, lineItem);
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a solution to your problem, but can you elaborate more on your use case. Here is the small sample answer, hope this might help you out to get started.

```
public class MyMaths {

    int a;

    public int getA() {
        return a;
    }

    public void setA(int a) {
        this.a = a;
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {

        Map map = new HashMap();
        MyMaths mayMaths = new MyMaths();
        map.put("obj", mayMaths);
        map.put("name", "Ankur");

        String expression1 = "obj.a = ( name == 'Ankur') ? 20 : 25";

        Serializable compiled1 = MVEL.compileExpression(expression1);

        MVEL.executeExpression(compiled1, map);

        System.out.println(mayMaths.getA());

    }
```

So here i am actually assigning the value to variable "`a`" of class `MyMaths`

Output - 20

Now change the value from 'Ankur' to 'XYZ', output will be 25.